# Importing (populating) data from an old database dump to a new database - Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, migration

I have a php app that I am porting to rails. I created the database schema in my rails app, and want to import some production data into the the sqlite db for testing - some users, badges table, etc. Is there an easy way to do this from an sql file, or some other type of database dump?

Comment: here is a little tutorial for that: http://www.frick-web.com/en/blog/import-old-database-in-new-scheme-with-mysql-and-rails - this example shows a database import in to a new schema with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sqlite, assuming you have created your tables you can use:

```
sqlite> .read <sqlfile.sql>
```

If the SQL file contains insert statements. Each statement should be end with a semi-colon.

You can use:

```
sqlite> .import <csvfilename.csv> <tablename>
```

If the CSV file is like this:

```
Data for Col1|Data for Col2|Data for Col3|...
```

or, if you want comma-separated values:

```
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import <csvfilename.csv> <tablename>
```